# multiple div having dynamic height and also to keep 2 divs that are side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to display the `div` content (having different heights) one after the other, with 2 `div`s side by side. I have tried to do this but I am getting space between `div`s having different heights.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <div class="itemlist">
        <div class="ItemView">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ItemView">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ItemView">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ItemView">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ItemView">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

```
.ItemView {
    width: 46%;
    float:left;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    text-align: left;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
    min-height: 90px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

### Current output:

[image: current output]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Here http://jsfiddle.net/Ga5nX/ is your example. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: if u notice in the above image there is a gap b/w 2nd and 3rd row of 1st column. i want to display one after the other with even space.

Comment: Can your HTML markup be changed? An image of the expected output would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should seperate the 2 columns and put all elements of a column in a floated container.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/a7A7b/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div class="itemlist">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="ItemView">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="ItemView">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.ItemView {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    text-align: left;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
    min-height: 90px;
    padding: 0;
}
.col{
    float:left;
    width:46%;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.big {
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: i have tried the above code but nothing has changed.. still i am not getting the even space.                                                    Thanks..

Comment: hi, i have added the required output image. pls check it out..            Thanks..

Comment: @user3588720 have you had a look at the fiddle? it does give even spaces bewteen the elements. Maybe you are using some other CSS code that overides the properties from my example. If you have a live example of your project, I'd be glad to have a look.

Comment: @web-tiki thanks for your reply... i have seen the fiddle. but div are displaying in 1 column. i have executed the above code in separate html file. i am not getting the even space. actually in the above code the height of the divs are same. if we add more content(different heights) space is coming.

Comment: without adding col class can we do?.. because i am using k2 component. i cannot insert div between the articles.(cannot insert the col class to display as 2 columns)